# Visual Studio Code - Start debug action

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have started using Visual Studio Code and have installed the Python plugin.

When I click F5 to start debugging I get the option of running "Python" and "Python Experimental. I would like one of them to be selected automatically to save time.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's configurable. Please select either of the options by clicking the settings icon in the debug area. For detailed tutorial follow this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Perfect! Thanks w1n5rx. Simply selecting the right debug configuration solved this issue for me.